# Delete Dock Widget in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, designer, qdockwidget

I added (via drag and drop) a `QDockWidget` to my GUI that I was editing in Designer...
Now I want to remove it.

Firstly, I selected the visible object and pressed the `Delete` key.
The Object disappeared.

However, the `QDockWidget` can be seen to still be present in the Object Inspector,
and when I try to save my `.ui`, I get the message:

```
The container extension of the widget MainWindow (QMainWindow)
returned a widget not managed by Designer dockWidget (QDockWidget)
when queried for page #2. Container pages should only be added by
specifying them in XML returned by the domXml() method of the custom
widget.
```

Clicking on the Widget in the Object Inspector and hitting the Delete key does nothing,
and the right-click context menu does not have the usual 'Remove' option.
How do I get rid of it?! 
:|

Specs:

```
Windows 7 32 bit  
PyQt4
```

Comment: I'd appreciate a response ASAP.
I can't save the GUI!

Comment: I managed to reproduce a similar error, but it still saved the file despite the error message.  Are you sure it's not being saved?

Comment: I didn't think it was, because after I tried to save it I compiled it to .py using pyuic4.
The produced py file did not contain all my objects from the ui file,
and caused errors.

However,
once I reopened that new .ui file in the Designer, the QDockWidgets had disappeared, and everything worked normally! :)
Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also had this problem - dockable windows in the object inspector which I couldn't see in the main window. Because I couldn't see them, I couldn't find a way to delete them.  However, when I saved the file, I ignored the warning messages (the same you had). When I reloaded the saved ui file, all the erroneous dock windows in the object inspector had disappeared.

Comment: It's a happy ending all round :)
I'm just going to choose this as an answer.
It pretty much has the solution.